# Select Radio Button in a group using Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to be able to select a radio button within a group (of radio buttons) identified by the name attribute:

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="exampleInputRadio" id="optionRadio1" value="1">
    <input type="radio" name="exampleInputRadio" id="optionRadio2" value="2">
    <input type="radio" name="exampleInputRadio" id="optionRadio3" value="3">
    <input type="radio" name="exampleInputRadio" id="optionRadio4" value="4">
</div>
```

I use the following code to do what I want:

```
public void exampleInputRadio(WebDriver driver, int option) {
    List<WebElement> radios = driver.findElements(By.name("exampleInputRadio"));
    if (option > 0 && option <= radios.size()) {
        radios.get(option - 1).click();
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundException("option " + option + " not found");
    }
}
```

The problem is that Selenium always selects the first radio button, no matter the value of `option` argument is.

And when I code this in the above method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < radios.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(radios.get(i).getAttribute("id"));
}
```

I get this output:

```
optionRadio1
optionRadio2
optionRadio3
optionRadio4
```

Comment: this worked absolutely fine for me. Can you post like what and how your options are invoked.

Comment: @nitinchawda Sorry, but I don't have the code in front of me, but even if I do `radios.get(3).click()` in the above method, the first radio button is selected. I use the latest version (2.41.0) of selenium if it can help.

Comment: Not sure if its related to version problem. I have firefox 29, chrome 34 and selenium 2.39 version. this works on both the browsers very well.

Comment: @user1177636 No I'm using Firefox 28

Comment: I found the solution. The inputs were into a `label` tag. Sorry for the inconvenience...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is absolutely working fine for me on Firefox 28.
I have tried something like this:

function:

```
public void exampleInputRadio(WebDriver driver, int option) {
        List<WebElement> radios = driver.findElements(By.name("exampleInputRadio"));
        if (option > 0 && option <= radios.size()) {
            radios.get(option - 1).click();
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundException("option " + option + " not found");
        }
    }
```

functions called:

```
TestClass tc = new TestClass();
tc.exampleInputRadio(driver, 1);
tc.exampleInputRadio(driver, 2);
tc.exampleInputRadio(driver, 3);
tc.exampleInputRadio(driver, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple work around could be using the `value` or the `id` attributed.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("optionRadio" + (option + 1))).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the work around but I want to use the "name" attribute, and don't know why it does not work

Comment: You could use a xpath with the name as "exampleInputRadio"  and id as "optionRadio" + (option+1)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use xpath, something like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='1]")).click();
```

Comment: Are you missing an apostrophe? e.g. `@value='1'`